# RxJava timeout, timer -- how to stay on the upstream thread?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a simple stream that emits on its thread. Then I have `timeout()`, which however then emits `Computation` by default. Is there a way to pass to `timeout()` the same thread as upstream emits on? **So it doesn't create unnecessary new thread?**

```
scanResults()
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     // part of library
     .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io()), Obserable.just(specialValue())
```

This I believe would spawn 2 threads, right?

Is there a way to pass a scheduler of current thread somehow to timeout argument so it stays on the upstream thread?

Maybe like `timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, { Scheduler(Thread.currentThread())}` if it makes sense, so it's single thread only

Comment: look at the available schedulers : `Schedulers.single()` - this is probably equivalent of `Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` or similar

Comment: well, not exactly what I want, upstream might be on Scheduler.io and if I apply debounce(Schedulers.io) that will because of implementation detail of IO spawn a new thread (if pool empty)

Comment: "upstream might be on Scheduler.io" - so use `observeOn(Schedulers.single())` when you want to switch the downstream? Debounce is on `computation()` by default as well.

Comment: thats way too simplistic. think zip(o1.subscribeOn(IO), o2.subscribeOn(IO).compose(foo)) and foo is what you are overriding, as per OOP, and you dont have knowledge it is IO upstream .. or should I pass the scheduler as argument to foo?

Comment: "thats way too simplistic" - not sure what you mean? "as per OOP" - this is functional programming, do you mean Encapsulation? io() is unbounded, meaning if you have lots of zip / flatMap() on io etc happening at once then you can get a silly amount of threads processing. You can't simple pluck what io() thread you want to use. I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Your question was "Is there a way to pass to timeout() the same thread as upstream emits on?" - my comments have answered that. Have more relevant code that would help (your upstream code you keep talking about?).

Comment: In general you can't return to the same thread when it is of the standard io or computation scheduler, and if your source is an eager generator, it wouldn't work as it holds onto the thread it is emitting items from. You could try with your own single-threaded schedulers (`Schedulers.from()`) injected everywhere upfront.

Comment: @akarnokd I see, okay maybe timering on computation is okay, but then I have to observeOn(io()) which would spawn a new thread. So you are saying that I cannot return to the thread of the upstream unless I make custom scheduler singlethreaded instance?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing such thing as you have to interpose into monad(Observable)  that you are going to interrupt by a timer. The way how you implement such behavior in a single thread is like:

```
val list = listOf(Task1, Task2, Task3)
while(checkTimer() && list.isEmpty().not()) {
    list.takeFirst().execute()
}
```

In a case you have only one operation encapsulated in a monad how are you going to check the time without interruption from another thread?

Comment: yes you are right, what my question should have been is how to observeOn the "upstream" thread after timer thread emits, without explicitly setting the scheduler -- so I dont need to carry instance manually, and also if it is io, it spawns a new thread regardless if scheduelr explicitly set

Comment: The thing is that you can't get back to the same thread that was interrupted by timer thread.